# Python polar clock-like plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot data in a clock-wise fashion using matplotlib in Python in the style of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898523/how-to-plot-points-on-a-clock). I noticed weird behaviour when plotting my data; the data points had the correct y value, but would not appear at the correct x values, i.e. times. I first thought that my data was erroneous, but upon recreating my problem with the following working example I came to the conclusion that the mistake must be somewhere else.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
equals = np.linspace(0, 360, 24, endpoint=False) #np.arange(24)
ones = np.ones(24)
ax.scatter(equals, ones)       

# Set the circumference labels
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))      

# Make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)       

# Place 0 at the top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)       

plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot:
[image]

I would have expected that the x values of the points line up with the hours, considering the definition of `equals`. It is currently defined as an angle, but I also tried defining it as an hour. Why is this not the case and how can I get my data to line up with the corresponding time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib expects angles to be in units of radians and not degrees (see the [open bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4986)). You can use the numpy function `np.deg2rad` to convert to radians:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
equals = np.linspace(0, 360, 24, endpoint=False) #np.arange(24)
ones = np.ones(24)
ax.scatter(np.deg2rad(equals), ones)       

# Set the circumference labels
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))      

# Make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)       

# Place 0 at the top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)       

plt.show()
```

This produces the following picture:

[image]

Alternatively, you could have changed your definition of equals to produce angles in terms of radians: `equals = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False)`

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! For those interested, to convert a time from a 24h clock to a radiant, simply multiply the time by 15 to obtain the degree and then convert it to radians (though there is certainly a more straight-forward solution).
`lambda t: np.deg2rad(t*15)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `equals` array is in degrees, but matplotlib expects radians. So all you need to do is make your angle measurements in radians.