# Matplotlib: Making Polar Plot with Logarithmic Angular Axis

Tags: matplotlib, circular-dependency, logarithm, polar-coordinates

I want to draw some circular axes to plot the artwork for an old-fashioned circular slide rule. In almost every example, polar plots have an angular axis of degrees or radians. I found one example of changing the labels to be like a clock (1 - 12), but I couldn’t see how to extend that technique to logarithmic scales.

I can draw the desired axis in a linear manner, as I see examples of making a logarithmic radial axis. But I can’t find a way to apply log scales to the angular theta axis.

A somewhat related issue, how can you use `matplotlib` to draw a single axis (e.g., no data, axis only)? This could be helpful for making nomographs, for example. In my use case, if I can’t plot the circular log scale directly, I could perhaps post-process a linear log scale into a circle — maybe.

[Here is an old circular slide rule](https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_690526) as an example. I’d like to make scales such as C or D (one complete log cycle in 360 degrees), A (two cycles) and K (three cycles).

Comment: Could you maybe link to the example you mentioned? Is it this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919275/python-polar-clock-like-plot-with-matplotlib

Comment: If you're following the question I mentioned above, the linearity stems from `np.linspace(0, 2pi, 24)` in `ax.set_xticks()`. If you want some kind of logarithmic scaling, you should opt for some logarithmic mapping that maps your tick points between 0 and 2pi instead of a `np.linspace`

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Kopfgeldjaeger/Clock_project) is the example I saw. But similar concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)


lim_min = 1             # ln(1) = 0
lim_max = np.e**(2*np.pi)  # ln(e**(2*pi)) = 2*pi (np.log = ln)
N_LABLES = 24
XTICKS = [np.log(x) for x in np.linspace(lim_min, lim_max, N_LABLES, endpoint=False)]

# Set the circumference labels
ax.set_xticks(XTICKS)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(N_LABLES))

# Make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# Place 0 at the top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)       

plt.show()
```

You can play with the exact scaling from 0 to 2pi to get the plot the way you want it. Figure produced:
[image]

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, for my application. I kept wanting to use the LogFormatter, like I would for a linear log axis, but finally I decided it wasn't suitable. There are only two levels of tick marks native to `matplotlib`, but to draw slide rule scales you need 3 or 4 levels. This approach lets me do that, albeit a little tedious. I will post my modification to your code below, which draws one cycle of a log scale. Thanks @ljbkusters

Answer (score 2):

Based on @ljbkusters answer, I crafted a single-cycle, circular log-base-10 scale. This will serve as a basis for more detailed plots for the final slide rule artwork.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
# Place 0 at the top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)       

# Polar plots don't have tick marks, 
# cannot draw outside the max radius set by ylim
# Remove the frame, and y-axis,
# * draw our own axis circle
# * draw our own tick marks (below)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_frame_on(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
angles = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0*np.pi, 100)
ax.plot( angles, 100*[95], color='black', lw=1.2 )

# Major
lim_min = 1 
lim_max = 10 
N_LABLES = 10
XTICKS = [2.0 * np.pi * np.log10(x) for x in np.linspace(lim_min, lim_max, N_LABLES-1, endpoint=False)]
ax.set_xticks(XTICKS)
# Set the circumference labels
ax.set_xticklabels(range(1, N_LABLES))
# Draw major tick marks
tick = [93,100]
for t in XTICKS:
    ax.plot([t,t], tick, lw=1.0, color='black')

# Minor
lim_min = 1 
lim_max = 10 
N_LABLES = 100
XTICKS = [2.0 * np.pi * np.log10(x) for x in np.linspace(lim_min, lim_max, N_LABLES-1, endpoint=False)]
ax.set_xticks(XTICKS)
# Draw minor tick marks
tick = [95,98]
for t in XTICKS:
    ax.plot([t,t], tick, lw=0.5, color='blue')

plt.show()
```

[image]